# MVC3 Html.ActionLink to sub-controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to get `Html.ActionLink()` to render a link to a path that looks like this?

```
/posts/1/comments/2
```

In my app, I have this route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "CommentRoute",
    "posts/{postId}/comments/{action}/{commentId}",
    new {
        controller = "Comments",
        action = "details",
        commentId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

What overload/set of parameters can I send to `Html.ActionLink` to get a pretty path like the one above?

If this isn't possible, is there a recommended implementation of a custom helper to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` will look at your route table to generate the approriate link.

You can call it as usual and it will use the correct URL:

```
@Html.ActionLink("details", "Comments", new { postId, action, commentId })
```